# Somar inputs checkbox e no final subtrair um

Tags: php, javascript, formulário

Reformulei essa pergunta, vou tentar ser mais objetivo.
Tenho esse campo no formulário:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde a área do código que calcula é essa:

```
  $( "div#molhos :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
            sub += $( this ).val() * $( this ).parent().find("select").val();

}); // each molhos
```

Até ai tudo bem, o que eu preciso é que no final do cálculo ele subtraia UM, exemplo: Se o usuário escolher o TRÊS MOLHO 1 e DOIS MOLHO 3 o total será de 5 molhos, correto? Daria R$ 7,50, mas eu quero que o resultado fique sempre com MENOS UM, ficaria o valor certo R$ 6,00.

A Regra seria, escolhendo UM molho só, sai de graça, a partir do segundo que iremos cobrar.

Não sei se ajuda, mas vai mais informações do código:
Isso fico no topo:

```
var str = "";
var id = "";
var sub = 0.00;
var taxa = 0;
var taxadeentrega = total - taxa;
var total = 0.00;
var qcount = 0;
var scount = 0;
var opc = 0;
var options = "";
for (i=1; i<21; i++){
    options += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>";
}
```

Essa é outra área do código que é mencionado o Molho:

```
<!--MOLHOS-->

        $( "div#molhos :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
              var sel = $(this).parent().children("select").val();
              str = str + $(this).parent().children("strong").text() + ": R$ " + $(this).val().replace(".", ",") + " x " + sel + " = R$ " + (($(this).val() * sel).toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",") + "<br>";
        })
        $('input[name=molhos]').val(str);
        str = "";
```

Mas acredito que a parte importante para criar essa regra é o primeiro desse post! Creio que é a Regra if, mas eu não conseguir fazer, tentei de tudo!!

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entedi sua dificuldade é em fazer o calculo total dos molhos, entao segue o codigo, baicamente da ultima parte.

```
var totalMolhos = 0;
var gratisQtd = 1;
var valorMolhoUnidade = 1.50;
var valorTotalMolhos = 0;
$( "div#molhos :checkbox:checked" ).each(function(i) {
    $totalMolhos = $( this ).val() * $('campo_com_a_quantidade_do_molho').val();
}); // each molhos

if(totalMolhos>0){
    /*aqui é so subtrair do total a quantidade de molhos gratis, no seu caso 1*/
    valorTotalMolhos = (totalMolhos-gratisQtd) * valorMolhoUnidade;
}
```

Comment: olha o código de outro campo que tenho no formulário, que funciona com o select. Esse não tem a opção de graça! `$( "div#sobremesas :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
     var sel = $(this).parent().children("select").val();
     str = str + $(this).parent().children("strong").text() + ": R$ " + $(this).val().replace(".", ",") + " x " + sel + " = R$ " + (($(this).val() * sel).toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",") + "<br>";
  })
  $('input[name=sobremesas]').val(str);
  str = "";`

Comment: A parte que faz o calculo: `$( "div#sobremesas :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
   sub += $( this ).val() * $( this ).parent().children( "select" ).val();
  }) //each sobremesas`

Comment: Eu poderia adaptar esse da Sobremesa para o Molho, só não sei onde coloco a opção de 1 é de graça. Ou seja IGUAL a uma escolha será 0 de cobrança

Comment: o que percebi do seu problema é o seguinte, voce so precisa saber quantos molhos foram selecionados, apos isso, voce subtrai quantos molhos gratis voce esta dando de graça, o restante é o que o cliente vai ter que pagar. O que eu fiz dentro do `each()` foi exatamente calcular o total de molhos que o usuario selecionou.

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que isso resolva seu problema:

```js
$('#molhos input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {

    var count = $('#molhos input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
    count = count == 0 ? 0 : count-1;
  
    var result = 1.50*count;
  
    $('#total').html('Total a pagar nos molhos R$ ' + result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="molhos">
  
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1"> Molho 1: R$ 1,50
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="2"> Molho 2 R$ 1,50
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="3"> Molho 3 R$ 1,50
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="4"> Molho 4 R$ 1,50
  </div>
  
</div>

<div id="total"></div>
```

Toda vez que um `checkbox` é alterado eu rodo a função para calcular o número de molhos selecionados e exibir a mensagem pro usuário de acordo, mas lembre-se que é importante realizar uma checagem adicional no lado do servidor!

Comment: Como fazer para pegar o valor maior ?

Comment: @Rafa Você pode usar o Math.max combinado com o spread operator pra pegar o valor máximo contido dentro de um array, ficaria assim: Math.max(...arr). Dá uma olhada [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

Answer (score 0):

Quando você der um Get no valor que o usuário inseriu na tela, efetue uma verificação... se o valor inserido for > 1 você cobra pela quantidade informada -1.

Ex:

```
if($_POST['qtdeMolhos'] > 1){
    $valor = 1.5*($_POST['qtdeMolhos']-1);
}else{
    $valor = 0;
}
```

Conseguiu compreender? Se ele informa 1 o valor será R$ 0,00 e qualquer valor maior que isso, ele multiplica o valor base R$ 1,50 pelo valor informado menos a quantidade que a casa dispõe como cortesia.

Comment: Não se interfere em algo mais já tenho no topo desse arquivo o seguinte código: `var str = "";
var id = "";
var sub = 0.00;
var taxa = 0;
var taxadeentrega = total - taxa;
var total = 0.00;
var qcount = 0;
var scount = 0;
var opc = 0;`

Comment: Acredito que não interfira... você somente está declarando e instanciando as variáveis antes. Tente implementar o código que passei acima para ver se vai funcionar. Implementei em PHP pois não sabia se essa verificação será feita no PHP ou no JavaScript.

Comment: Ok, vou tentar, obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: Eu montei esse formulário todo com a ajuda desse site, entendo pouco de programação, estou estudando ainda. Esse aqui seria o código dessa área no PHP: `<!-- MOLHOS -->
<div id="molhos">
<span class="titulo">Escolha o seu Molho!</span><br>
<span style="font-size: 12px"><strong><em style="font-size: 11px">(Você tem direito a um molho, totalmente grátis) </em></strong></span>
<br>
<div style="color: #FFFFFF">espaço</div>
<div><input type="checkbox" value="1.50"> <strong>MOLHO 1</strong><span>: R$ 1,50 - Quant.: <select></select></span></div>
`

Comment: Olha o código de outro campo que tenho no formulário, que funciona com o select. Esse não tem a opção de graça! `$( "div#sobremesas :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() { var sel = $(this).parent().children("select").val(); str = str + $(this).parent().children("strong").text() + ": R$ " + $(this).val().replace(".", ",") + " x " + sel + " = R$ " + (($(this).val() * sel).toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",") + "<br>"; }) $('input[name=sobremesas]').val(str); str = "";` Poderia adaptar esse para o molho, com a opção de 1 grátis. Tem como?

Comment: A parte que faz o calculo: `$( "div#sobremesas :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
   sub += $( this ).val() * $( this ).parent().children( "select" ).val();
  }) //each sobremesas`